# Error caused by rewriting the default React Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

#### What I want to do

Following the create a new React app commands, I am trying to change the screen that is displayed in the browser when the following is executed.

I have already executed the following command and confirmed that it works, but I want to edit the HTML and Javascript files to show only `Hello World!`.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

#### Prerequisite

In the procedure Creating a new React app, the contents of index.js are as follows.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

#### Error

It seems to be running, but nothing is displayed in the browser as white screen with nothing has shown.

What needs to be modified to display `Hello World!`?
[image: Screen Shot]

```bash
$ npm start
Compiled successfully!

You can now view my-app in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully
```

#### Code

The public and src folders under the my-app folder were deleted, leaving only `public/index.html` and `src/index.js`, and the rest were deleted.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```java
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

#### Dev Env

- node v18.15.0
- react 18.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render` is no longer supported in React 18; use `ReactDOM.createRoot` instead.

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'))
        .render(<h1>Hello World!</h1>);
```